# ArcGIS current location

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.3, arcgis

I am having trouble with the location service which gets the location of where i am at using ArcGIS. Here is the part of the code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.activityView startAnimating];
    //self.mapView.layerDelegate = self;
    self.mapView.touchDelegate = self;
    self.mapView.calloutDelegate = self;
    NSURL *mapUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:kTiledMapServiceURL];
    AGSTiledMapServiceLayer *tiledLyr = [AGSTiledMapServiceLayer tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL:mapUrl];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:tiledLyr withName:@"Tiled Layer"];

        //Create Bus Graphic layer
    AGSGraphicsLayer *busGraphicLayer = [AGSGraphicsLayer graphicsLayer];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:busGraphicLayer withName:@"BusLayer"];

//Create Graphic layer
    AGSGraphicsLayer *graphicLayer = [AGSGraphicsLayer graphicsLayer];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:graphicLayer withName:@"GraphicsLayer"];

    //Create Service layer
    AGSGraphicsLayer *serviceLayer = [AGSGraphicsLayer graphicsLayer];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:serviceLayer withName:@"ServiceLayer"];

    //Create Path layer
    AGSGraphicsLayer *pathLayer = [AGSGraphicsLayer graphicsLayer];
    [self.mapView addMapLayer:pathLayer withName:@"PathLayer"];
 }

- (void) showMarkingOnMap:(Service *) ser
{
    id<AGSLayerView> graphicsLayerView = [self.mapView.mapLayerViews objectForKey:@"ServiceLayer"];
    AGSGraphicsLayer *graphicsLayer = (AGSGraphicsLayer*)graphicsLayerView.agsLayer;
    [graphicsLayer removeAllGraphics];

    // Create a symbols png graphic
    AGSPictureMarkerSymbol *genSymbol = [AGSPictureMarkerSymbol pictureMarkerSymbolWithImageNamed:@"pushpin.png"];
    ServiceInfoTemplate *infoTemplate = [[ServiceInfoTemplate alloc] init];
    AGSGraphic *genGraphic;
    AGSPoint *genPt;
    NSMutableDictionary *dic= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic setObject:[ser name] forKey:@"NAME"];
    if([ser.location isEqualToString: @"\n"] || (ser.location == nil)){
        [dic setObject:@"" forKey:@"DESC"];
    } else {
        [dic setObject:[ser location] forKey:@"DESC"];
    }
    genPt = [AGSPoint pointWithX:[[ser xcoordinate] floatValue]
                                y:[[ser ycoordinate] floatValue]
                 spatialReference:self.mapView.spatialReference];

    destinationX = [[ser xcoordinate] floatValue];
    destinationY = [[ser ycoordinate] floatValue];

    genGraphic = [[AGSGraphic alloc] initWithGeometry:genPt symbol:genSymbol attributes:dic infoTemplateDelegate:infoTemplate];
    [graphicsLayer addGraphic:genGraphic];

    [graphicsLayer dataChanged];

    [self.mapView zoomWithFactor:0.1 atAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(destinationX, destinationY) animated:NO];
    [self.mapView centerAtPoint:genPt animated:YES];
}
```

This method is where i called the current location

```
- (IBAction) directionAction:(id)sender{
    NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www....&routeStops=%f,%f;%f,%f&routemode=DRIVE&avoidERP=0"",         
                        self.mapView.gps.currentPoint.x, self.mapView.gps.currentPoint.y, destinationX, destinationY];

}
```

this `self.mapView.gps.currentPoint.x` returns me a 0 but it is supposed to return the current x coordinate where i am.
Any one know what is wrong with it?

Comment: You should probably try including some more relevant code. How is the map view set up, what does it depend on? Are there any initialisation methods you've not called, etc.?

Comment: What is self.mapView.gps? What data type is x? You are trying to log an object (using %@), but coordinates are usually expressed as doubles.

Comment: .x is from AGSPoint.h file which is given by the ArcGIS.

Comment: in that file .x is expressed as a double. Are you sure you are using the right format specifier in your stringWithFormat?

Comment: yup it is the right format,i have tested with hardcoded values. it doesn't seems to get the current point of my location

Answer (score 0):

I don't see from your code that you enabled the gps object on the mapView.  You need to enable it first by setting [enable property](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/iphone/reference/interface_a_g_s_g_p_s.html) to YES.  And then wait for the gps to have a valid location (currentPoint != nil) before you try to use the currentPoint.  You can set a key value observer on the currentPoint property and wait for the notification that it changed and check that it is valid and use it then.

```
self.mapView.gps.enabled = YES;   // enable the GPS

// add the observer like this:
[self.mapView.gps addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentPoint" options:0 context:nil];
```

Then you add a method to get the notification when it changess:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"currentPoint"]) {
        AGSPoint *point = self.mapView.gps.currentPoint;
        if (point==nil) return;

        // now we have a valid gps location
    }
}
```

Hope that gives you some idea.